# Possible to set column ordering in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

Is there any possible configuration to set database column ordering in entity framework code first approach..?

All of my entity set should have some common fields for keeping recordinfo

```
public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
public DateTime ModifiedAt { get; set; }
public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }
public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
```

I want to keep this fields at the end of the table. Is there any possible EF configuration that i can use to config this rather than keeping this fields at the end of my model class.

Comment: What if I have for instance 3 levels of inheritance and still have complete control fo column ordering? Thx!

Comment: If you are using ef core, check the following post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51443459/how-to-sort-inheritance-columns-ordering-in-ef-core-2-1/57178076#57178076

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using Entity Framework 6 since column ordering [is not yet supported](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2272) in EF Core.

You can use either data attributes or the fluent API to set column order.

To use a Data Attribute to set column order, reference `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` and use the [`ColumnAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.columnattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). You can also set the column name with this attribute if you want it to differ from the property name.

```
[Column("CreatedAt", Order=0)]
public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
[Column("CreatedBy", Order=1)]
public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
```

Note the Order parameter is zero-based.

See also: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/column-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Alternatively, you can use the Fluent API in the `OnModelCreating` method in your DbContext class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //Configure Column
    modelBuilder.Entity<EntityClass>()
                .Property(p => p.CreatedAt)
                .HasColumnOrder(0);
}
```

See also: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-property-mappings-using-fluent-api.aspx

This way is a bit more verbose but you can have a more bit control over what's happening.

Comment: Thanks Steve for the great replay. I have one more question let say if i set column order for few fields in my model then what will be the order of the remaining column(I mean the column without order number in the same model).

Comment: @IshaJohn I believe they are put after your numbered columns in alphabetical order. I'm not sure what happens if you don't start at 0 however.

Comment: I can see in EF6 "Order" property on ForeignKeys dosen't apply. If i have a property of some other class referred in my  class, foreign key column for that property will be appearing last. Does anyone have solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
```

Code:

```
[DisplayColumn("Name" , Order = 1)]
public int UserName { get; set; }
```

Notice: column order by default takes a big number so if you ordered only this column it will be first one in the table unless you ordered another column with a lower order number which is in this case : 0