# How to sort inheritance columns ordering in EF Core 2.1?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ef-core-2.1

I used EF Core 2.1 to create SQL Server database,
but database columns ordering doesn't put inheritance columns in the last,
the following is my entities code:

```
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}

public class RssBlog : Blog
{
    public string RssUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Current columns ordering are:

```
1.RssUrl
2.BlodId
3.Url
```

I want it in database like this:

```
1.BlodId
2.Url
3.RssUrl
```

Could you tell me how to fix the database columns ordering?
Thanks!

I'm beginner for English, if my words or sentences have some problems, I'm so sorry.

Comment: That's an open issue of EF Core, as you can see on [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11314)

Comment: @Caldazar Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an open issue of Entity Framework Core that I have submitted while EF Core 2.1 Preview 1 released but has not been fixed yet (current version 2.1).

### Update On 06-Oct-2018

Entity framework core team has planned to fix this issue in EF Core 3.0 release at the start of next year.

Here is the details: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11314

Answer (score 0):

A trick that I see while researching a solution to the problem.

When you add migration you will get following scaffolded migration file

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "RssBlog",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    BlogId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    Url = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    RssUrl = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_RssBlog", x => x.BlogId);
                });
```

Table columns order result is below;

```
BlogId
Url
RssUrl
```

You can reorder the columns in the scaffolded migration file;

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                    name: "RssBlog",
                    columns: table => new
                    {
                        RssUrl = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                        BlogId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                            .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                        Url = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
                    },
                    constraints: table =>
                    {
                        table.PrimaryKey("PK_RssBlog", x => x.BlogId);
                    });
```

After we reorder, table columns order like below;

```
RssUrl
BlogId
Url
```

So before ef core team publish column order feature ([related issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10059)) we can order our columns like above.

[Detailed blog post](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/new-features-of-entity-framework-core-2-1-better-column-ordering-in-initial-mig/)

Comment: Thank you for providing a good solution. Even though it's a good solution, but still troublesome as I need to personally adjust them if I have so many entities.