# Base model column order at the end of the table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43246727/possible-to-set-column-ordering-in-entity-framework) as this is entity framework core and that is for normal entity frame work. If you read my question you would've noticed that.

The project I am working on is written in .NET Core 2.2/ I currently have a bunch of models for my entity framework core code-first implementation, they all inherit from `BaseEntity` and is defined as follows:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

But whenever I generate a new migration using `Add-Migration` it puts the `CreatedAt` and `UpdatedAt` columns at the beginning of the table. Is there anyway to specify a column order or something that will put the columns at the end of the table instead of the beginning.

Comment: [`ColumnAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.columnattribute?view=netcore-2.2) isn't in either framework, but it's use by both frameworks for the same purpose...  even [the documentation tells you to use it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/columns).

Comment: @ErikPhilips- My apologies, I didn't mention that I already tried that and it had absolutely no effect on the column ordering.

Comment: [Looks like there is a bug in the code itself, even though you're still suppose to use the ColumnAttribute](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11314).

Comment: @ErikPhilips - Seems I'm shit out of luck, thanks though.

Comment: Still add them though, for future development/developers :)